# Java удаление элемента массива из самого элемента

Tags: java, arraylist

Можно ли удалить экземпляр-элемент ArrayList изнутри самого этого элемента, если все эти элементы имеют ссылку на этот массив?
Как элемент найдет себя в массиве?

```java
public class element 
{
  public list1 motherlist 
  public void deletefrommotherlist()
  {
    for (element i:this.motherlist.elements)
    {
      if (i==this) ???????? или как???
    };
  }
}

public class list1 {public ArrayList<element> elements}
```

Comment: `motherlist.elements.remove(this)`

Answer (score 0):

Классы пишутся с большой буквы в JAVA.

Можно удалить через итератор, можно через прямое обращение list.remove(ссылка или значение,смотря какой "дженерик")

Если будете удалять через форыч, то прилетит 100 % эксепшн, так как вы выйдете за пределы листа.